# Zendesk JWT setup through Azure AD

Tags: .net, json, jwt, visual-studio-2019, zendesk

I've been struggling with this for a few days now and could use some help, I am unable to get the payload data to be correctly pulled and redirected through zendesk.

Im working in visual studio 2019 to test this code, i opened a new project chose .net web then linked with our azure domain, it created the application, i opened the homecontroller.cs document and modified it (as you can see below)

after running code to see if it worked (start without debugging) it loads the microsoft redirect page and i can sign in after sign in it returns a red error at the top of the page that says that

Invalid data from remote sign-in mechanism. Missing name or email.

```
{
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IConfiguration configuration;
    private string SUBDOMAIN => "**********";
    private string SHARED_KEY => "6YR****************************************";
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
        int timestamp = (int)t.TotalSeconds;``
        var email = HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
        var payload = new Dictionary<string,
            object>()
        {
            {
                    "alg",
                    "HS256"
                }, {
                    "typ",
                    "JWT"
                }, {
                    "iat",
                    timestamp
                }, {
                    "jti",
                    Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                }, {
                    "name",
                    HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
                }, {
                    "email",
                    email
                }
            };

        IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new HMACSHA256Algorithm();
        IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
        IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
        IJwtEncoder encoder = new JwtEncoder(algorithm, serializer, urlEncoder);
        var token = encoder.Encode(payload, SHARED_KEY);
        string redirectUrl = "https://" + SUBDOMAIN + ".zendesk.com/access/jwt?jwt=" + token;
        string returnTo = HttpContext.Request.Query["return_to"].ToString();
        if (returnTo != null)
        {
            redirectUrl += "&return_to=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnTo);
        }
        return Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Privacy()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
    }
}
```

}

the expected result is that when users go to zendesk web address (https://domain.zendesk.com) they will be redirected to microsoft login, user will login with their account in azure ad, it will then redirect user back to zendesk and sign them in.